# How to remove quotes in my product description string?

Tags: preg-replace

I'm using OSCommerce for my online store and I'm currently optimizing my product page for rich snippets. 
Some of my Google Indexed pages are being marked as "Failed" by Google due to double quotes in the description field.

I'm using an existing code which strips the html coding and truncates anything after 197 characters.

```
<?php echo substr(trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($product_info['products_description']))), 0, 197); ?>
```

How can I include the removal of quotes in that code so that the following string:

```
<strong>This product is the perfect "fit"</strong>
```

becomes:

```
This product is the perfect fit
```

Comment: Why do you replace `\s\s+`? Just replace `"`; `...preg_replace('/"/', '', ...`

Comment: @Toto That alone won't work, because it would target _all_ double quotes, anywhere they appear, both inside and outside of HTML tags.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It will work because they use `strip_tags` before the call to `preg_replace`, so there're no more html tags.

Comment: @Toto No...I'm saying maybe the OP (or the reader of this question in the future) _only_ wants to remove double quotes _inside_ the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Happened with me, try to use:

```
tep_output_string($product_info['products_description']))
```

`"` becomes `&quot;`

Comment: Thanks but that's not working form .I still see the double quotes

Comment: That's a function from osCommerce, I had the same issue and it worked. By the way I use the header tags module ht_product_schema.php and switched to tep_output_string for descriptions.

Comment: If you want to try the module here it's: https://github.com/gburton/Responsive-osCommerce/blob/master/includes/modules/header_tags/ht_product_schema.php
I've edited this part: "description" => tep_output_string($product_info['products_description']));
instead of "description" => substr(trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($product_info['products_description']))), 0, 197) . '...');

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `preg_replace_callback` here:

```
$input = "SOME TEXT HERE <strong>This product is the perfect \"fit\"</strong> SOME MORE TEXT HERE";
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    "/<([^>]+)>(.*?)<\/\\1>/",
    function($m) {
        return str_replace("\"", "", $m[2]);
    },
    $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
SOME TEXT HERE This product is the perfect fit SOME MORE TEXT HERE
```

The regex pattern used does the following:

```
<([^>]+)>  match an opening HTML tag, and capture the tag name
(.*?)      then match and capture the content inside the tag
<\/\\1>    finally match the same closing tag
```

Then, we use a callback function which does an additional replacement to strip off all double quotes.

Note that in general using regex against HTML is bad practice.  But, if your text only has single level/occasional HTML tags, then the solution I gave above might be viable.